# How to type function that will infer params with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function called `invoke` which currently is typed like this:

```js
export type InvokeType = <T = InvokeResponseTypes, Params = any>(
  methodName: InvokeMethodNameTypes,
  args?: Params
) => Promise<T>;

// for context, Invoke is a signalR method to call methods on a SignalR server.
```

`InvokeMethodNameTypes` are simply strings that call methods, like `"GetUser"` or `"GetEvent"` etc.

Each `InvokeMethodNameType` has corresponding `args` (Params) or none at all and I would use it like so:

```js
const data = await invoke<GetEventResponseType, GetEventArgs>("GetEvent", { eventId })
```

This works but I do not feel like it is the correct approach to what I actually want to achieve.

Is it possible to type the `invoke` function so when passing a string such as "GetEvent" the arguments are automatically inferred to the correct object type?

Comment: please share reproducable example

Comment: @captain-yossarian https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-khayyam-uqutm?file=/src/index.ts

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code in the sandbox:

```
function myFunction(stringArg: 'person'): { name: string, age: number }
function myFunction(stringArg: 'car'): { make: string, model: string }
function myFunction(stringArg: any): any
{
  if (stringArg === "person") {
    return {
      name: "John",
      age: 20
    };
  }

  if (stringArg === "car") {
    return {
      make: "Mazda",
      model: "6"
    };
  }
}

let personResult = myFunction("person");
let personName = personResult.name;     // Okay
let personAge = personResult.age;       // Okay
let personMake = personResult.make;     // Error
let personModel = personResult.model;   // Error

let carResult = myFunction("car");
let carName = carResult.name;       // Error
let carAge = carResult.age;         // Error
let carMake = carResult.make;       // Okay
let carModel = carResult.model;     // Okay
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzyAkm)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know you could declare multiple functions and pass different Typescript declarations like that.

Comment: It's [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) in the documentation.

Comment: @KarlTaylor. [Another way](https://tsplay.dev/Wyvldw) that works for arrow functions.